# Context switching kernel processes in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, context-switch

Consider the process keventd. It spends all it's lifetime in kernel mode.
Now, as far as I know, Linux checks if a context switch is due, while the process is switching from kernel mode to user mode, and as far as I know, keventd will never switch from kernel mode to user mode, so, how will the Linux kernel know when to switch it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the kernel were to do as you say, and only check whether a process is due to be switched out on an explicit user-to-kernel-mode transition, then the following loop would lock up a core of your computer:

```
while (1);
```

Obviously, this does not happen on normal desktop operating systems. The reason why is *preemption*, where after a process has run for its time slice the kernel gets an alarm, steps in, and forcibly switches contexts as necessary.

Preemption could in principle work for kernel processes too. However, I'm not sure that's what `keventd` does - it's more likely that it voluntarily relinquishes its time slice on a regular basis (see `sched_yield`, a userspace call for the same effect), especially since the kernel can be configured to be non-preemptible. That is a kernel process' prerogative.

Comment: while(1) would switch to kernel mode every scheduler_tick(), so the kernel will find out that the process's timeslice is over while it is in the kernel mode, and would do p->need_resched = 1,and while trying to switch to user-mode, it will call to schedule()..

Comment: @Shmoopy Correct! I didn't get from your original post that you understood that there were implicit kernel-mode transitions that happen when the program is not making a system call, so I clarified. I'll add the word "explicit" to my answer. Of course, `scheduler_tick` still fires even when you're in kernel space, and you can have tickless kernels...

Comment: There will still be calls to scheduler_tick() for keventd (or any kernel process for that matter), but  what scheduler_tick does (among other things) is : if (!--p->time_slice) { p->need_recsched = 1 }, so my question is, when will the linux kernel check for that flag if there's never a kernel-to-user transition for a kernel process (keventd in our example).

Comment: @Shmoopy Read the last paragraph of my answer. As a general rule, kernel processes give up their own slices.